# Javascript inheritance and method overriding

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Assume I have a class like this:

```
function Widget() {
    this.id = new Date().getTime();
    // other fields
}
Widget.prototype = {
    load: function(args) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

From this class I created some other classes which inherit the same prototype but have some added methods. What I want to do is being able to define a load() method in the sub-classes which first calls the parent method and then execute some code. Something like:

```
SpecialWidget.prototype = {
    load: function(args) {
        super.load(args);
        // specific code here
    }
}
```

I know there's no super keyword in Javascript but there must be a way to do this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can simulate it like this:

```
SpecialWidget.prototype = {
    load: function(args) {
        Widget.prototype.load.call(this, args);
        // specific code here
    }
}
```

Or you can create your own super property like this:

```
SpecialWidget.prototype.parent = Widget.prototype;

SpecialWidget.prototype = {
    load: function(args) {
        this.parent.load.call(this,args);
        // specific code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the simplest solution! Thank you

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment, I have an object that is already inherited from a class and I want to specialise a method basically.

Answer (score 3):

so first, you set up your 'subclass' like so

```
function SubClass(name) {
    Super.call(this);

    // stuff here
}

SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass(null);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

and then you can do

```
SuperClass.prototype.theMethod.apply(this);
```

from within a subclass implementation to specifically invoke the super's implementation.

Comment: For those, like me, that questioned the difference between this approach and the call in the answer, the short answer is there is none. The long answer is provided by mozilla here... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but you could do something like this:

```
function Widget() {
    this.id = new Date().getTime();
}
Widget.prototype.load = function(args) {
   alert( 'parent load' );
};

SpecialWidget = function(){};

   // Make the prototype of SpecialWidget an instance of Widget
var proto = SpecialWidget.prototype = new Widget;

   // Give the prototype a function that references the "load" from Widget
proto.parent_load = proto.load;

   // Give SpecialWidget its own "load" that first calls the parent_load
proto.load = function( args ) {
    this.parent_load( args );
    alert( 'special load' );
};

var inst = new SpecialWidget;

inst.load();
```

This makes the prototype of `SpecialWidget` an instance of `Widget` so that it inherits all that `Widget` has.

Then it makes a reference to the `load()` of `Widget` called `parent_load()`, and creates its own `load()` that calls the `parent_load()` when invoked.

Comment: You can use `Object.create(Thing.prototype)` rather than `new Thing`if you don't cater for old clients.

Answer (score 1):

### Since mid-2015 (ECMAScript 2015), javascript has Classes and super

Here's the link: https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/, see section 12.3.5 (super) and 14.5 (Class definitions).

How your code would look with those changes:

```js
class Widget() {
    constructor() {
        this.id = new Date().getTime();
        // other fields
    }
    load(args) {
        // do something
    }
}

class SpecialWidget extends Widget {
    load(args) {
        super.load(args);
        // specific code here
    }
}
```

The closest I got to the previous syntax (without using `class` but using `super`) was using Object.setPrototypeOf:

```js
// UNCHANGED
function Widget() {
    this.id = new Date().getTime();
    // other fields
}
Widget.prototype = {
    load: function(args) {
        // do something
    }
}

// slightly changed to declare SpecialWidget
function SpecialWidget() {}

// changed to define load as an method, and not a property with function as value
SpecialWidget.prototype = {
    load(args) {
        super.load(args);
        // specific code here
    }
}

// here's the key
Object.setPrototypeOf(SpecialWidget.prototype, Widget.prototype);
```

The declaration of `load` was changed because `super` can be used inside methods, but not functions. So, instead of `load: function(args) { body }`, it's simply `load(args) { body }`.

But, there's a caveat: with this solution, elements of `SpecialWidget` will **not** inherit the id defined as `new Date().getTime()`. I don't think there's a workahound (without using classes or duplicating code declaring `this.id` inside `SpecialWidget`).

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to store the old value of the `load` method in a closure, if you did your overriding like this:

```
function Widget() {
    this.id = new Date().getTime();
    // other fields
}

Widget.prototype = {
    load: function(args) {
        // do something
        alert("Widget Prototype Load");
    }
};

function SpecialWidget(){
};

SpecialWidget.prototype = new Widget();

(function(){
    var oldLoad = SpecialWidget.prototype.load;
    SpecialWidget.prototype.load = function(){
        oldLoad();
        alert("new Load");
    };
}());


var x = new SpecialWidget();
x.load();
```

It works, but I'm not sure if it's the best method.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Simple Javascript Class](https://github.com/reduardo7/sjsClass):

```
Class.extend('Widget', {
  load: function () {
    alert('foo');
  }
});

Widget.extend('SpecialWidget', {
  load: function () {
    this.super();
    alert('bar');
  }
});

new Widget().load(); // Alert: 'foo'
new SpecialWidget().load(); // Alert: 'foo' and 'bar'
```

Take a look at [Simple Javascript Class Project](https://github.com/reduardo7/sjsClass), [Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) and [Inheritance Patterns in JavaScript](http://www.bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php).