# How to call super/base methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, super

I have to implement following code in Javascript, but cannot find equivalent of `super.say()` in javascript. How to do this translation ?

```
class Foo {
    public void say() {
      System.out.println("foo");  
    }
}


class Bar extends Foo {

    static int counter = 0;

    public void say() {
        super.say();
        counter++;
        System.out.println("bar " + counter); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably rewrite it without a notion of "classes"; the idiomatic JavaScript approach is not necessarily the idiomatic "Java OOP" approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an article that describes it in detail: http://joshgertzen.com/object-oriented-super-class-method-calling-with-javascript/

Basically, you need to store a reference to your base method, then call it in the "derived" (perhaps "shadowed" might be a better word here) method.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `super` doesn't work in Javascript as in Java because there's no notion of classes. Without a class, you can't have a descendant, and thus `super` is useless in that context.

You could implement something `super`-like, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4777567/493749).

Comment: This is not a fair conclusion (there is no `super` keyword is correct, but otherwise it doesn't seem tangential). Traditional "OOP" classes can be *entirely emulated* in JavaScript through prototypal inheritance; as can virtual, super, and non-virtual methods.

Comment: @user2864740 I didn't say you couldn't do it, I said JS doesn't have a notion of classes. You can totally implement something similar to `super` in JS, just not the way the OP is looking for.

Comment: So, then back to the question "*How* to implement super in javascript"?

Comment: If one "can't have a descendant", then how does [[prototype]] work? Or how does `instanceof` work? The issue with `super` is subtly different, and is caused because JavaScript doesn't directly allow a mechanism to skip the "MRO" (and virtual members) along the [[prototype]] chain.

Comment: Here is a trivial counter-example to the descendant claim: `a = function () {}; b = function () {}; b.prototype = new a; (new b) instanceof a` results in true.