# How to inject properties and methods of one class into another class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`#javascript` `#nodejs`

I have 3 classes (A, B, C) in my script. Class B extends class A and inside class B is a method which calls a new instance of class C.

Sample Code:

```
// First class
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Eve';
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    getC() {
        // This is where I needed a solution
        return new C();
    }
}

class C {
    constructor() {
        this.address = 'Market Village';
    }

    getAllInfo() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

The expected output if run the code below is what it should be:

```
let b = new B(18);
let info = b.getC().getInfo();
console.log(info); // {address: 'Market Village'}
```

But what I wanted to happen is for class C to inherit all properties and methods of class A and B so that class C is able to use the properties and methods of both classes.

I've tried several approaches but none works.

Attempt #1:

This approach injects all the properties and methods of class A and B into class C but the problem is it throws an error saying `cannot set ... of undefined`, for some reason, the methods of class C are not read:

```
getC() {
    C.calls(this);
}
```

Attempt #2

This approach reads all the methods of class C and injects all the properties of both class A and B but not its methods. So again, when you call any of the methods of class A and B inside class C, it throws an error:

```
getC() {
    let _classC = new C();
    Object.assign( _classC, this );

    return _classC;
}
```

Is there a way to call a new instance of class C and inject all the properties and methods of class B and A?

*Note that class C must be a standalone class and should not extend either classes.*

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry my bad, noted your comment about not extending the classes just after I commented. Nevermind!

Comment: No worries, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to re-think your architecture.

Comment: Yeah, it's complicated but I kind of need it to work that way -:

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Eve';
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(age) {
        super();
        this.age = age;
    }

    getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    getC() {
        let _classC = new C();
        Object.assign( _classC, this );

        return _classC;
    }
}

class C {
    constructor() {
        this.address = 'Market Village';
    }

    getInfo() {
        return this;
    }
}
let b = new B(18);
let info = b.getC().getInfo();
console.log(info);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that approach. It does inject the properties but you can't call any of the methods from class A and B in class C.

Comment: `let b = new B(18);
let c = b.getC();
console.log(c,c.getInfo());`

Comment: Yes, that code works. But the other problem is that when calling `this.getAge()` method inside class C, it throws an error.

Comment: Oh so you want to inheriting "methods"? Hope this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777522/javascript-inheritance-and-method-overriding